# 文章内の文字列をreplaceを使用して置換したい

Tags: python, python3

置換したい文章を`body0x_before="ooooo"`の形で変数に入れて、文章の中で`replaceWord =` の中にヒットする文字列があれば、その文字列をreplaceするという処理を行いたいです。

置換したい文章は数千個あり、例では文章の長さは短いですが、実際に`body0x_before="ooooo"`に入れる文章は１つにつき1000文字以上あります。

例)
`body04_before="i like mcdonalds"`は `["mcdonalds","chicken"]`がヒットするので、アウトプットが下記のように出るのを期待しています。

```
  before             after
    ・　　　　　　　　　　　・
    ・　　　　　　　　　　　・
    ・　　　　　　　　　　　・
5 i like mcdonalds　　i like chicken
```

根本的に何か間違っているように思えるのですが、どのように調べたら良いか分からずご教授いただけると幸いです。

スクリプト

```
import os.path, time, re
import pandas as pd
import csv


body01_before="test1234"
body02_before="test9012"
body03_before="test5678"
body04_before="i like mcdonalds"
body05_before="I was born april"

replaceWord = [
                ["test9012","te1210st"],
                ["test5678","8579"],
                ["test1234","1349"],
                ["april","August"],
                ["mcdonalds","chicken"],

]

cols = ['before','after']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=cols)

for word in replaceWord:
    
    body01_after = re.sub(word[0], word[1], body01_before)
    body02_after = re.sub(word[0], word[1], body02_before)
    body03_after = re.sub(word[0], word[1], body03_before)
    body04_after = re.sub(word[0], word[1], body04_before)
    body05_after = re.sub(word[0], word[1], body05_before)

    df=df.append({'before':body01_before,'after':body01_after}, ignore_index=True)
    
#df.head()
print(df)

df.to_csv('test_replace.csv')
```

現状の結果

```
     before     after
0  test1234  test1234
1  test1234  test1234
2  test1234      1349
3  test1234  test1234
4  test1234  test1234
```

期待する結果

```
  before    after
1 test1234  1349
2 test9012  te1210st
3 test5678  8579
4 april     I was born August
5 mcdonalds i like checkin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

replaceWord = [
    [ 'test9012', 'te1210st'],
    [ 'test5678',     '8579'],
    [ 'test1234',     '1349'],
    [    'april',   'August'],
    ['mcdonalds',  'chicken'],
]

before = [
    'test1234',
    'test9012',
    'test5678',
    'i like mcdonalds',
    'I was born april',
]
after = [reduce(lambda i, j: i.replace(*j), replaceWord, text) for text in before]
df = pd.DataFrame({'before': before, 'after': after})

print(df)

#
             before              after
0          test1234               1349
1          test9012           te1210st
2          test5678               8579
3  i like mcdonalds     i like chicken
4  I was born april  I was born August
```

Comment: 加えて、replaceWordとbefore のリストを、before のキーワードをkeyとした辞書としたほうが、リスト順序の入力ミスを防げて良いかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。非常に助かりました。

Comment: replace(*j) の(*j)は何を意味するのでしょうか？調べてみたのですがうまく解説されてるものがなくご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `replace(j[0], j[1])` と同じ意味になります。「python リストのアンパック」で調べてみて下さい。

Comment: ご丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます！非常に助かりました。